# Git Merge 2 repos follow up

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

This is sort of a follow up of:
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories)

I am trying to merge one git repo (project-a) into another (probject-b). Project b was a copy from project-a.

Specifically for this answer:
If you want to merge project-a into project-b:

```
cd path/to/project-b
git remote add project-a path/to/project-a
git fetch project-a
git merge project-a/master # or whichever branch you want to merge
git remote remove project-a
```

It is VERY important that project-b's code does not merge back to project-a.

Would this solution only merge all of project-a's updates to project-b, but not merge project-b's updates back to project-a?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. You added project-a as a remote and you fetched its contents but you didn't touch it. SO yes only project-b gets affected and project-a is how it was.

Specifically, if you want to merge the project-a changes to your project-b/X branch you can do this (skipping remote add/remove parts)

```
  git checkout X
  git merge project-a/X (or whatever branch you want to merge)
```

Then again the project-a/X changes came to project-b/X and project-a was not affected.

Comment: Thanks! Will it also not delete over all the edits I've made to project-b? Meaning, it will allow me to error on the side of project-b, if there is a conflict?

Comment: yes exactly. it will try to smart merge stuff, if it cannot, it will alert about conflict and wait for you to do your merge manually.

See: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge